# PhantomJS teamcity config

Tags: testing, phantomjs, automated-tests, teamcity

In a teamcity config I have build step which runs PhantomJS tests. It is a "Command Line" step with custom script. The script looks like:

%PhantomJS% CreateEntityPopupTest\unit.htm
%PhantomJS% ExcelImportPopupTest\unit.htm
...
etc.

So it runs each qunit test package mentioned in the htm page. But I didn't manage to find a way to point PhantomJS (phantomjs-1.9.0-windows) to a folder, not to a single file. So there would be no need to change the config each time when we add new files with tests.

Comment: PhantomJS runs JavaScript files and not html files. Perhaps %PhantomJS% is a wrapper with a script that opens the given html file. Maybe you can see if you can change this wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I used Chutzpah to wrap this behavior for use in TeamCity. Chutzpah can run tests written in QUnit, Jasmine or Mocha and uses PhantomJS as the headless test runner.

https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah

I installed it on the build agents and added it to the path on the machine.

Now I simply add a Command line runner step called 'Run JS Test' in my build template. Command line is simply:

```
chutzpah.console.exe %jsTestFolder%
```

Then I just define the parameter for each project pointing to a folder... chutzpah does the rest.